# Docker container IP address difference

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

In introductory Docker tutorial https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#share-your-image, container is started with `docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello`, and container server is accessible from `http://localhost:4000`, as expected.
But when I tried to run Postgres in container, with Dockerfile

`FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER=user-ms
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345`

and command `docker run -p 5432:5432 user-db`, server cannot be accessed at localhost, only at `psql -h 172.17.0.2`.

Why these two cases differ?
According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/, both should be in bridge network by default, with `172.17.0.1` gateway. How comes that first example is than accessible on localhost?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Can you check the `NetworkSettings` output of `docker inspect <container-name` output?

Comment: The error was ```psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?```,
please check comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure? I tried the following:

```bash
docker run --rm -it -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=user-ms -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345 postgres
```

I tried establishing connections to it from the Docker host…

Localhost worked:

```bash
psql --user user-ms -h localhost
```

And the local IP address worked also:

```bash
psql --user user-ms -h "$(ifconfig \
| grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" \
| grep -v 127.0.0.1 \
| awk '{ print $2 }' \
| cut -f2 -d: \
| head -n1)"
```

Comment: You are right, my mistake. Used `psql` without specifying host, which meant it tried Unix domain sockets. Was so occupied with setting docker, thought it must be something with its configuration.